# css div hover Affects child elements differently

Tags: html, css

I have a thumbnail list. the image is floated to the left. I want the text to move and overlap the image halfway when the text region is hovered upon. I have tried using position and more recently translate but it just moves my text header and body differently only when I hover on them. I want to move the entire div. How do I do that?

```css
#gallery{
    margin-left:370px;
    width: auto;
    height:385px;
    position: relative;

}

#content{
    padding:20px 10px 0;
    margin:0px 20px 20px 0;
    color:#888888;
    float: left;

}
#content a,p, ul, li, h3{
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
}

#content>ul{
    list-style-type: none;
    width:700px;
    padding:0px;
    clear:left;
}

#content>ul>li h3,h6 {
  font: bold 20px/1.5 Helvetica, Verdana, sans-serif;
    color:white;

}
#content>ul>li h3:hover {
    color:#66cc33;
}
#content ul> li{
    position: relative;
    background-color: #141414;
    padding:0 0 0 0;
}
#content li:nth-child(even){
    background-color:#333333;
}

#content li:first-child{
    padding-top: 0 !important;
}

#content > ul> li p{
  font: 200 12px/1.5 Georgia, Times New Roman, serif;
  text-align: justify;
}
#content li {
  padding: 10px;
  overflow: auto;
}

#content li:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 3px;
}
.thumbContainer{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
.thumbContainer img {
    float: left;
    margin: 0 15px 0 0;
    height:93px;
    width:144px;
}
.latest-news-container{
    -webkit-transition: translate 2s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: translate 2s ease-in-out;
    transition: translate 2s ease-in-out;
}
div.latest-news-container :hover{
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50px);
    transform:  translate(-50px);
    -moz-transform:  translate(-50px);
    background-color: inherit;
}
```

```html
<ul>
                    <li>
                        <div class="thumbContainer">
                        <img src="Images/7.jpg" alt="Willian Borges" >
                        </div>
                        <div class="latest-news-container">
                        <h3>Willian Aiming for the Top</h3>
                        <p>
                            The former Liverpool midfielder will have brought back painful memories for Jose Mourinho and Chelsea fans after he posted a hilarious nod to the
                            infamous "ghost goal" incident from the 2004-05 season.... <a class="btn" href="#">Read more</a>
                        </p>
                        </div>

                    </li>

                    <li>
                        <div class="thumbContainer">
                        <img src="images/8.jpg" alt="Lukaku" >
                        </div>
                        <div class="latest-news-container">
                        <h3>Lukaku Goal Drought Continues</h3>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent euismod ultrices ante, ac laoreet nulla vestibulum adipiscing. Nam quis justo in augue auctor imperdiet.</p>
                        </div>
                    </li>

                    <li>
                        <div class="thumbContainer">
                        <img src="images/9.jpg" alt="Hart">
                        </div>
                        <div class="latest-news-container">
                        <h3>Bad Treatment at the City</h3>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent euismod ultrices ante, ac laoreet nulla vestibulum adipiscing. Nam quis justo in augue auctor imperdiet.</p>
                        </div>
                    </li>

                    <li>
                        <div class="thumbContainer">
                        <img src="images/10.jpg" alt="Ronaldo">
                        </div>
                        <div class="latest-news-container">
                        <p>
                        <h3>CR7 Smiling to the Bank</h3>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
                            Praesent euismod ultrices ante, ac laoreet nulla vestibulum adipiscing. Nam quis justo in augue auctor imperdiet.</p>
                        </p>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                </ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the space between `container` and `:hover`

```
div.latest-news-container :hover{
```

Change it to:

```
div.latest-news-container:hover{
```

Comment: Thanks alot. But now, it is not sliding over with the background. It pics only text. using translate covers the image completely